# Method with FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

The following constantly reports the same error.

```
public static ArrayList<File> findMatches(File directory, String pattern) throws FileNotFoundException {
60         ArrayList<File> container = new ArrayList<File>();
61 
62         return container;
63     }
```

And I initialize it in the following way

```
ArrayList<File> matched = findMatches(new File("hw9"), "FileFinder.java");
```

The error:
     error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Any solutions?

### Edit

Found out how to do it finally!

```
public static ArrayList<File> findMatches(File directory, String pattern) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<File> container = new ArrayList<File>();

    try {
        if (!directory.exists() && !directory.canRead() && !directory.isDirectory()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
        File[] fileStack = directory.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileStack.length; i++) {
            if (patternMatches(pattern, fileStack[i].getName())) {
                container.add(fileStack[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
    return container;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "constantly reports the same error"? The method you've given definitely *won't* actually throw FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Just edited my question. Heres the error above

Comment: Do I add the following if else statement?   If (!directory.exists()) { throw new FileNotFoundException() }

Comment: @SeanKwon: Well that wouldn't fix the error that you've now said you're getting. It looks like you need to learn about exception handling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any solutions?

Well, you've got three options:

- Change `findMatches` so that it doesn't declare that it throws `FileNotFoundException` (at the moment it definitely won't throw it anyway)
- Catch the `FileNotFoundException` in the calling code
- Declare that the method calling `findMatches` throws `FileNotFoundException`

We can't tell which is most suitable from the very small amount of information you've provided.

You also need to read the [Exceptions part of the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/), or the exception coverage of any good Java book/tutorial. It's very important that you understand *why* you're getting this error, and why the above changes would fix it.

Comment: @Apurv: Oh you *always* need to check the answer. I regularly talk absolute twaddle.